# Find by data-dojo-id on Intern-runner functional test?

Tags: dojo, intern

Is there a way to grab a reference to a widget instance by data-dojo-id on an Intern functional test running on a standalone server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Dojo released a `dijit-intern-helper` module that you can include in your tests to help with this:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'intern/dojo/node!dijit-intern-helper/helpers/dijit',
    'require'
], function (registerSuite, assert, dijit, require) {
    var url = '../../index.html';

    registerSuite({
        name: 'Todo (functional)',

        'get widget node': function () {
            return this.remote
                .get(require.toUrl(url))
                .then(dijit.nodeById('yourWidgetId', 'rootNodeToLookUnder'))
                .getProperty('value')
                .then(function (val) {
                    assert.ok(val == 'Test :)');
                });
        }
    });
});
```

You can read more about it on [this Sitepen blog post](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2016/01/13/simplified-dijit-functional-testing/) or straight on the [project Github page](https://github.com/SitePen/dijit-intern-helper).

Comment: Note that there's a difference between working with a widget node and working with the widget itself. For example, calling `.getProperty('value')` in a Command chain behaves much differently than calling `dijit.getProperty('yourWidgetId', 'value')` as a `then` callback.

Comment: My widgets don't have a fixed id I can safely pass to helpers, just a fixed data-dojo-id, so I ended up adding a lang.getObject line to them